# Calculating Angular Velocity Needed to Travel a Certain Distance Via the Magnus Effect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, trigonometry

Aight so I've been at this for several days and with how much it's slowing the project down I've made the hard decision to come beg the internet.
I'm working on a physics-based golf game in Unity and am working on implementing the magnus effect. This is my calculation for tangential force based on torque:

```
    void FixedUpdate()
        {
            float _BallRadius = .0427f;
            float _halfmass = Mathf.Sqrt(_BallRadius*.5f );
            float _vv = new Vector3(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x, 0, 
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z).magnitude;
            //MAGNUS FORMULA (SIDESPIN ONLY)//
            float _mag = -((1.429f * Mathf.Abs(_vv)* (2 * Mathf.PI * _halfmass * 
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().angularVelocity.y))) * (_BallRadius * .5f);
            Vector3 _xmagdir = new Vector3(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x, 0, GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z);     
GetComponent<Rigidbody().AddForce(Vector3.Cross(_xmagdir.normalized,Vector3.up)*_mag, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }
```

This works well enough, but now I need to figure out the correct amount to give the ball to get this result: 
[Diagram of Desired Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcfg3.png)

I've tried several different approaches, and I've come to the conclusion that this is mostly comes down to trigonometry. Here is where I'm at currently (this is before the tangential direction is applied to the final velocity vector):

```
Vector3 GetMagnusTorque(float Distance, Vector3 V_BallForce, float xdir)
{
    float _BallRadius = .0427f;
    float _halfmass = Mathf.Sqrt(_BallRadius*.5f);
    Vector3 v = GO_Camera.transform.InverseTransformDirection(V_BallForce);
    float HorizontalRange = Distance;
    //THIS IS THE LATERAL DISTANCE WE NEED TO TRAVEL//
    float opposite = (Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Tan(Mathf.Deg2Rad * xdir))) * (HorizontalRange*.5f);
    //THIS IS THE TIME IT WILL NEED TO TAKE//
    float time = ((2 * v.magnitude * Mathf.Sin((2 * (v.normalized.y )))) / -Physics.gravity.y);
    //THIS IS THE SPEED THE MAGNUS EFFECT WILL NEED TO PRODUCE//
    float linearSpeed =Mathf.Abs((opposite/time))*Mathf.Sign(xdir)Mathf.Abs((opposite/time))*Mathf.Sign(xdir)*(Time.timeScale+Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    return GO_Camera.transform.TransformDirection((((linearSpeed /( 2 * Mathf.PI * _halfmass * (_BallRadius * .5f))) / 1.429f))*Mathf.Deg2Rad*GO_PGolfBall.transform.up);
}
```

[Logic behind this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LepRz.png)

The result is very inconsistent based on xdir and V_BallForce, sometimes travels further, sometimes barely at all. This has been a pretty sobering adventure in discovering that I'm pretty bad at math. 
If anyone has any advice for this issue I would forever be in your debt.

Update: Here is some visualization of the issue:
[visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGpO7.png)

Update: I figured I should include a code sample of the function GetMagnusTorque is called from, to better put things in context:

```
 void BallApplyForce()
    {
        //_rmult is a [0,1] value that is dependent on the accuracy of the player's swing//
        float _rmult = GetRMult();
        //GETS BALL READY BY ENABLING PHYSICS AND SETTING ITS ROTATION TO THE CAMERA//
        GO_PGolfBall.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(0, GO_Camera.transform.rotation.y, GO_Camera.transform.rotation.z, GO_Camera.transform.rotation.w);
        GO_PGolfBall.GetComponent<SCR_GOLFBALLCONTROL>().B_PhysicsActive = true;
        //YDIR = PITCH, XDIR = YAW. V_ContactPoint is a [-1,1] Vector2 used similar to Mario Golf//
        Vector3 _vdir = Vector3.zero;
        float ydir = ((Mathf.Rad2Deg * DIC_Clubs[I_CurrentClub].LandAngle) + (-2.5f * (.1f) * (DIC_Clubs[I_CurrentClub].LoftAngle * Mathf.Rad2Deg)));
        float _xdir = Mathf.Rad2Deg * (-(V_ContactPoint.x) * (DIC_Clubs[I_CurrentClub].LoftAngle)*3f);

        _vdir.y = ydir;
        _vdir = _vdir.normalized;
        _vdir.y *= Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        //MAX DISTANCE OF THE CLUB BEING USED TO METERS//
        float _dist = ((DIC_Clubs[I_CurrentClub].MaxDistance * F_UPower) * _rmult) * .9144f;

        //GET FORWARD AND UPWARDS VELOCITIES BASED ON THE DISTANCE GIVEN, XDIR ISN'T FACTORED FOR NOW//
        float Vi = Mathf.Sqrt(_dist * -Physics.gravity.y / (Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * _vdir.y * 2)));
        float Vy, Vz;
        Vy = Vi * Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad*_vdir.y);
        Vz = Vi * Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad*_vdir.y);
        GO_Camera.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, GO_Camera.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
        Vector3 _velo = GO_Camera.transform.TransformVector(new Vector3(0f, Vy, Vz));

        //CALCULATE VERTICAL ANGULAR VELOCITY, THIS DOESNT NEED TO FOLLOW ANY SORT OF PATTERN FOR NOW//
        float _verRoll = Mathf.Sign(V_ContactPoint.y - .1f) * ((.7135f) * _dist) * Mathf.Sin(DIC_Clubs[I_CurrentClub].LoftAngle +
            ((Mathf.Abs(V_ContactPoint.y + .1f)) * (DIC_Clubs[I_CurrentClub].LaunchAngle))) * 60 * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
        GO_PGolfBall.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(Vector3.Scale(GO_PGolfBall.transform.right, new Vector3(1, 0, 0)) * _verRoll, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        //CALCULATE HORIZONTAL ANGULAR VELOCITY//
        Debug.Log("MAGNUS CALC:" + GetMagnusTorque(_dist, _velo, _xdir));
        GO_PGolfBall.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddTorque(GetMagnusTorque(_dist, _velo, _xdir), ForceMode.VelocityChange);

        //APPLY XDIR TO THE CAMERA ANGLE AND RECALCULATE VELOCITY//
        GO_Camera.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, GO_Camera.transform.eulerAngles.y+_xdir, 0);
        _velo = GO_Camera.transform.TransformVector(new Vector3(0f, Vy, Vz));

        //APPLY VELOCITY//
        GO_PGolfBall.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(_velo, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
```

Update 11/21: I'm currently in the process of faking it through trial and error. But for those still interested in solving this anomaly, I may have found in issue in how I'm calculating the direction to apply the side-spin derived force to the ball. Hitting the ball with a lob wedge, which has a maximum distance of 70 yards and a loft angle of 60 deg, the desired curve looks something like this: [Lob Wedge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD2Zf.png) This obviously makes no sense, because the ball flies behind the golfer for a short period of time. I'll report back with the final numbers and calculations, though it will not answer the question it could help point it in the correct direction.

Comment: This question eventually comes down to a coding problem. All of the 'physics' could have been easily abstracted while retaining the message.

Comment: I could be misinterpreting what you mean, but this seems to be the opposite to me. Given a formula for force over time based on torque, an initial torque must be set such that by the end of a time calculated from horizontal range and velocity, the projectile's velocity in the tangent direction is equal to negative its tangent velocity at the start.

Comment: Is the problem 2D or 3D? It currently looks like a mixture of both, because although the velocity's Y-component is assumed to be zero, so is the *angular* velocity's Y-component. A 3D simulation has no such constraints, but the angular velocity should *only* have an effective Y-component in the 2D case.

Comment: Vertical spin is done separately, this is purely for side spin. angularVelocity.y is used because that is the axis for the side spin. Oh I see though, angularVelocity.z shouldn't be factored into the side-spin calculation. I'll update the code with this fix, but the main issue should persist since angularVelocity.z isn't applied on hit.

Comment: The 2D top-down case is fairly simple - the ball travels in a circular arc; the 3D case, when gravity is taken into account, might not be analytical (you might need numerical integration).

Comment: I would guess the problem is your code doesn't account for Time.deltaTime anywhere, so depending on your framerate, you will get more or less force applied.  A good trick is to do dimensional analysis to make sure you are actually accounting for all the variables you need to and are returning the value in the units you expect.  Is there a reason why you didn't use the F / L = pvG formula from wikipedia instead of trying to match the curve?

Comment: Did some more testing and updated the function with the results. Everything before linearSpeed is definitely correct now. Through debugging I found that like you said, Time.deltaTime should definitely be accounted for. The formula I'm using for lateral magnus force is that same formula (where 1.429 = p), but with the vortex strength formula integrated into it. The return statement is the same formula inverted, solving for angular velocity instead of force. I'll update again once/if I figure out how to integrate Time.deltaTime.

Comment: I've updated the post with this formula:
float linearSpeed =Mathf.Abs((opposite/time))*Mathf.Sign(xdir)*(Time.timeScale+Time.fixedDeltaTime);
Which may or may not be correct implementation of Time.fixedDeltaTime, but when xdir = 33 and Distance = 237.744 (and V_BallForce is the correct value to reach that distance), it results in a perfect curve.
If either value differs, the function falls apart.

Comment: Added an image of the phenomenon. The debug lines are correct; If torque is set to zero, it will travel along the half hypotenuse, if angle is zero, it will land at the end point.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment; it turns out that even with gravity, the general 3D problem still has an analytical solution, so long as the angular velocity stays constant. Is this the case in your situation?

Comment: Yes, angular velocity is constant for the time being to help isolate the issue.

Comment: One possibility; Since xdir is applied (after angular velocity is applied) to the force vector in angle only and not magnitude, this causes the total distance traveled to not match the distance calculated in the function. I may try that later, however the unknown here is if the magnus effect itself would have an impact on distance instead of just xdir.

Comment: Nevermind, whatever the issue is, that probably isn't it.

Comment: Uhhh.. Is it supposed to be GO_Camera.transform on the last line instead of GO_PGolfBall.transform?

Comment: Yeah, the camera angle changes during the frame that the ball is hit to a vector that helps define the direction the ball should travel. It may seem a bit jank, but it works.